# What is WRONG with MySQL Query? Slow, and has Null fields

Tags: mysql, database, join, query-optimization

At work I have to address a business requirement for a system I am building. It's a startup so I'm wearing a few hats. This is not my forte.

Among many other APIs, there is one where we have to make an HTTP request to an API fronting data for a MySQL 5.7 database for a Point of Sale system.

There are some hitches:

1. The API doesn't include much in the way of error messages, such as syntax errors. I do get a 521 if, for instance, I'm trying to add keys with the same name to the result.
2. The API is practically undocumented.

We need the sales of all ordered items that has been closed on a given date, the Close_Date. This information is housed over several tables:

1. `orders`: contains all orders, outstanding (`Closed=0`) or completed (`Closed=1`) and the date the till was closed (`Close_Date`). It does not have any idea what the orders are, but it has a subtotal, and tax information and other data not relevant here.
2. `orders_item`: contains all the items that have been ordered and are associated with an order on the field `orders_item.Order_ID = orders.ID.

   - An `itemID` is assigned to an item when it is ordered. As above, and order is made up of items by `itemID. Each items is associated with an order by its orderID. A row representing an item has its unique ID, itemPLU. This is required information. This table knows nothing of the modifications ('ingredients' or 'options') associated with an item ordered.
3. `orders_options`: contains the options one has with a dish, like which soup, which dessert. An option is associated to an item ordered by the `itemID` field. Options have additional costs, and as they are solid items, need to be counted in inventory so we must know.
4. `orders_ingredients`: contains the things you can add to a dish, like extra cheese or toppings on a pizza, or spicy mayo in your cubano sandwich instead of regular. An ingredient that has been ordered is associated to an ordered item by the `itemID` field.

A row in a valid result would look like consist of an item ordered on the date given by Close_Date. The values in the columns returned give a complete record of a sold item, unique identifiers ('****PLU') for items, options, and ingredients, will be matched to items in the customer's inventory database in our platform, after some parsing. These items have dollar value, and represent inventory to be accounted for.

### Partial Schema

Here is the code itself:

```sql
#MySQL 5.7.12
#please drop objects you've created at the end of the script 
#or check for their existance before creating
#'\\' is a delimiter

select version() as 'mysql version';

#
# TABLE STRUCTURE FOR: orders
#

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `orders`;

CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `DateClose` datetime NOT NULL,
  `DatePreorder` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Table_ID` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `Client_ID` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `User_ID` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Delivery_ID` mediumint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `SubTotal` decimal(13,4) NOT NULL,
  `Tax1` decimal(13,4) NOT NULL,
  `Tax2` decimal(13,4) NOT NULL,
  `Tax3` decimal(13,4) NOT NULL,
  `Tax4` decimal(13,4) NOT NULL,
  `Tax5` decimal(13,4) NOT NULL,
  `Tax6` decimal(13,4) NOT NULL,
  `NonTaxable` decimal(13,4) NOT NULL,
  `NonSale` decimal(13,4) NOT NULL,
  `Tax_Rounding` decimal(13,4) NOT NULL,
  `Total` decimal(13,4) NOT NULL,
  `Device` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `Client_Name` varchar(48) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Profile_ID` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Bill` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `Completed` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `Closed` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `Prepared` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Close_Date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Note` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Reason` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Void_By` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `IP` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `Deleted` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `Closed` (`Closed`,`Deleted`,`Completed`),
  KEY `DateClose` (`DateClose`,`Deleted`,`Completed`),
  KEY `Table_ID` (`Table_ID`,`Deleted`,`Completed`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci COMMENT='All Order information'
 PARTITION BY RANGE (`ID`)
(PARTITION `pYear` VALUES LESS THAN (5) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `pCurrent` VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB);

INSERT INTO `orders` (`ID`, `Date`, `DateClose`, `DatePreorder`, `Table_ID`, `Client_ID`, `User_ID`, `Delivery_ID`, `SubTotal`, `Tax1`, `Tax2`, `Tax3`, `Tax4`, `Tax5`, `Tax6`, `NonTaxable`, `NonSale`, `Tax_Rounding`, `Total`, `Device`, `Client_Name`, `Profile_ID`, `Bill`, `Completed`, `Closed`, `Prepared`, `Close_Date`, `Note`, `Reason`, `Void_By`, `IP`, `Deleted`) VALUES (1, '2019-08-10 14:13:48', '2020-06-08 04:25:15', '2019-08-08 07:38:29', 55, 0, 0, 0, '1620.9100', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', 0, 'fli', '', 0, 0, 1, 0, '2020-06-13 22:04:35', 'Odio minima et blanditiis sunt numquam.', '', 0, 255, 0);
INSERT INTO `orders` (`ID`, `Date`, `DateClose`, `DatePreorder`, `Table_ID`, `Client_ID`, `User_ID`, `Delivery_ID`, `SubTotal`, `Tax1`, `Tax2`, `Tax3`, `Tax4`, `Tax5`, `Tax6`, `NonTaxable`, `NonSale`, `Tax_Rounding`, `Total`, `Device`, `Client_Name`, `Profile_ID`, `Bill`, `Completed`, `Closed`, `Prepared`, `Close_Date`, `Note`, `Reason`, `Void_By`, `IP`, `Deleted`) VALUES (2, '2019-10-11 14:14:52', '2019-08-01 16:12:46', '2020-03-10 17:23:23', 20, 0, 0, 0, '2099.8200', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', 0, 'xslt', '', 0, 0, 1, 0, '2019-12-24 17:08:24', 'Impedit facere culpa autem libero.', '', 0, 255, 0);
INSERT INTO `orders` (`ID`, `Date`, `DateClose`, `DatePreorder`, `Table_ID`, `Client_ID`, `User_ID`, `Delivery_ID`, `SubTotal`, `Tax1`, `Tax2`, `Tax3`, `Tax4`, `Tax5`, `Tax6`, `NonTaxable`, `NonSale`, `Tax_Rounding`, `Total`, `Device`, `Client_Name`, `Profile_ID`, `Bill`, `Completed`, `Closed`, `Prepared`, `Close_Date`, `Note`, `Reason`, `Void_By`, `IP`, `Deleted`) VALUES (3, '2020-06-12 04:51:41', '2020-03-01 23:53:55', '2019-07-13 12:40:22', 46, 0, 0, 0, '224.7000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', 0, 'twds', '', 0, 0, 1, 0, '2020-02-03 17:32:05', 'Et dolorem eum consequatur et vitae sed. ', '', 0, 255, 0);
INSERT INTO `orders` (`ID`, `Date`, `DateClose`, `DatePreorder`, `Table_ID`, `Client_ID`, `User_ID`, `Delivery_ID`, `SubTotal`, `Tax1`, `Tax2`, `Tax3`, `Tax4`, `Tax5`, `Tax6`, `NonTaxable`, `NonSale`, `Tax_Rounding`, `Total`, `Device`, `Client_Name`, `Profile_ID`, `Bill`, `Completed`, `Closed`, `Prepared`, `Close_Date`, `Note`, `Reason`, `Void_By`, `IP`, `Deleted`) VALUES (4, '2019-10-05 16:20:34', '2019-10-14 17:10:30', '2020-05-23 21:10:45', 6, 0, 0, 0, '791.7700', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', 0, 'sitx', '', 0, 0, 1, 0, '2019-12-17 22:56:45', 'Et quidem perferendis .', '', 0, 255, 0);
INSERT INTO `orders` (`ID`, `Date`, `DateClose`, `DatePreorder`, `Table_ID`, `Client_ID`, `User_ID`, `Delivery_ID`, `SubTotal`, `Tax1`, `Tax2`, `Tax3`, `Tax4`, `Tax5`, `Tax6`, `NonTaxable`, `NonSale`, `Tax_Rounding`, `Total`, `Device`, `Client_Name`, `Profile_ID`, `Bill`, `Completed`, `Closed`, `Prepared`, `Close_Date`, `Note`, `Reason`, `Void_By`, `IP`, `Deleted`) VALUES (5, '2019-07-25 06:14:04', '2019-09-07 16:22:43', '2019-08-10 23:09:17', 13, 0, 0, 0, '197.5300', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', 0, 'wcm', '', 0, 0, 1, 0, '2020-06-13 22:04:35', 'Magnam facilis magni .', '', 0, 255, 0);
INSERT INTO `orders` (`ID`, `Date`, `DateClose`, `DatePreorder`, `Table_ID`, `Client_ID`, `User_ID`, `Delivery_ID`, `SubTotal`, `Tax1`, `Tax2`, `Tax3`, `Tax4`, `Tax5`, `Tax6`, `NonTaxable`, `NonSale`, `Tax_Rounding`, `Total`, `Device`, `Client_Name`, `Profile_ID`, `Bill`, `Completed`, `Closed`, `Prepared`, `Close_Date`, `Note`, `Reason`, `Void_By`, `IP`, `Deleted`) VALUES (6, '2020-06-06 09:53:50', '2019-08-14 16:13:30', '2020-03-03 03:04:10', 12, 0, 0, 0, '1360.5000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', 0, 'wm', '', 0, 0, 1, 0, '2019-07-16 19:29:05', 'Odio aut voluptatem ', '', 0, 255, 0);
INSERT INTO `orders` (`ID`, `Date`, `DateClose`, `DatePreorder`, `Table_ID`, `Client_ID`, `User_ID`, `Delivery_ID`, `SubTotal`, `Tax1`, `Tax2`, `Tax3`, `Tax4`, `Tax5`, `Tax6`, `NonTaxable`, `NonSale`, `Tax_Rounding`, `Total`, `Device`, `Client_Name`, `Profile_ID`, `Bill`, `Completed`, `Closed`, `Prepared`, `Close_Date`, `Note`, `Reason`, `Void_By`, `IP`, `Deleted`) VALUES (7, '2019-09-12 09:29:49', '2019-09-25 13:15:44', '2020-03-16 10:09:15', 37, 0, 0, 0, '1574.0400', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', 0, 'torrent', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, '2019-08-18 15:44:07', 'Quia veniam fugit necessitatibus laboriosam accusamus nihil. Reiciendis delectus repellendus minus.', '', 0, 255, 0);
INSERT INTO `orders` (`ID`, `Date`, `DateClose`, `DatePreorder`, `Table_ID`, `Client_ID`, `User_ID`, `Delivery_ID`, `SubTotal`, `Tax1`, `Tax2`, `Tax3`, `Tax4`, `Tax5`, `Tax6`, `NonTaxable`, `NonSale`, `Tax_Rounding`, `Total`, `Device`, `Client_Name`, `Profile_ID`, `Bill`, `Completed`, `Closed`, `Prepared`, `Close_Date`, `Note`, `Reason`, `Void_By`, `IP`, `Deleted`) VALUES (8, '2020-03-18 11:10:46', '2019-11-12 19:37:15', '2020-02-02 19:59:45', 10, 0, 0, 0, '628.2900', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', 0, 'sv4crc', '', 0, 0, 1, 0, '2019-09-08 23:21:28', 'Repellat possimus quod excepturi.', '', 0, 255, 1);
INSERT INTO `orders` (`ID`, `Date`, `DateClose`, `DatePreorder`, `Table_ID`, `Client_ID`, `User_ID`, `Delivery_ID`, `SubTotal`, `Tax1`, `Tax2`, `Tax3`, `Tax4`, `Tax5`, `Tax6`, `NonTaxable`, `NonSale`, `Tax_Rounding`, `Total`, `Device`, `Client_Name`, `Profile_ID`, `Bill`, `Completed`, `Closed`, `Prepared`, `Close_Date`, `Note`, `Reason`, `Void_By`, `IP`, `Deleted`) VALUES (9, '2019-09-14 19:16:31', '2020-02-19 14:04:16', '2020-02-18 18:13:03', 14, 0, 0, 0, '2067.1800', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', 0, 'h263', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, '2020-03-29 10:20:48', 'Aut quis nemo provident dolorum numquam rerum explicabo. ', '', 0, 255, 1);
INSERT INTO `orders` (`ID`, `Date`, `DateClose`, `DatePreorder`, `Table_ID`, `Client_ID`, `User_ID`, `Delivery_ID`, `SubTotal`, `Tax1`, `Tax2`, `Tax3`, `Tax4`, `Tax5`, `Tax6`, `NonTaxable`, `NonSale`, `Tax_Rounding`, `Total`, `Device`, `Client_Name`, `Profile_ID`, `Bill`, `Completed`, `Closed`, `Prepared`, `Close_Date`, `Note`, `Reason`, `Void_By`, `IP`, `Deleted`) VALUES (10, '2019-12-28 20:13:14', '2020-04-04 13:48:34', '2020-04-04 17:41:15', 19, 0, 0, 0, '2063.3100', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', 0, 'sid', '', 0, 0, 1, 0, '2020-06-13 22:04:35', 'Aliquam dolores voluptates repellendus voluptatem omnis sit doloribus explicabo.', '', 0, 255, 0);


#
# TABLE STRUCTURE FOR: orders_ingredient
#

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `orders_ingredient`;

CREATE TABLE `orders_ingredient` (
  `ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Item_ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `Ingredient_uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Change_uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Account` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Price` decimal(13,4) NOT NULL,
  `Tax_Type` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 31,
  `Qty` smallint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `Modifier` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `Deleted` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `Account` (`Account`,`Deleted`),
  KEY `Item_ID` (`Item_ID`,`Modifier`,`Deleted`,`Price`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC COMMENT='individual item per order'
 PARTITION BY RANGE (`ID`)
(PARTITION `pYear` VALUES LESS THAN (2) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `pCurrent` VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB);

INSERT INTO `orders_ingredient` (`ID`, `Item_ID`, `Ingredient_uid`, `Change_uid`, `Account`, `Name`, `Price`, `Tax_Type`, `Qty`, `Modifier`, `Modified`, `Deleted`) VALUES (1, 1, 800, 0, 2, 'a', '1.5600', 31, 20, 0, '2019-07-12 20:17:09', 0);
INSERT INTO `orders_ingredient` (`ID`, `Item_ID`, `Ingredient_uid`, `Change_uid`, `Account`, `Name`, `Price`, `Tax_Type`, `Qty`, `Modifier`, `Modified`, `Deleted`) VALUES (2, 2, 1130, 0, 3, 'e', '4.6300', 31, 1, 0, '2019-08-15 15:29:30', 0);
INSERT INTO `orders_ingredient` (`ID`, `Item_ID`, `Ingredient_uid`, `Change_uid`, `Account`, `Name`, `Price`, `Tax_Type`, `Qty`, `Modifier`, `Modified`, `Deleted`) VALUES (3, 3, 948, 0, 8, 'v', '0.9100', 31, 17, 0, '2020-02-25 20:47:51', 0);
INSERT INTO `orders_ingredient` (`ID`, `Item_ID`, `Ingredient_uid`, `Change_uid`, `Account`, `Name`, `Price`, `Tax_Type`, `Qty`, `Modifier`, `Modified`, `Deleted`) VALUES (4, 4, 987, 0, 5, 'e', '3.4800', 31, 12, 0, '2019-07-14 01:06:13', 0);
INSERT INTO `orders_ingredient` (`ID`, `Item_ID`, `Ingredient_uid`, `Change_uid`, `Account`, `Name`, `Price`, `Tax_Type`, `Qty`, `Modifier`, `Modified`, `Deleted`) VALUES (5, 5, 856, 0, 3, 'x', '2.1600', 31, 5, 0, '2020-01-11 19:28:40', 0);
INSERT INTO `orders_ingredient` (`ID`, `Item_ID`, `Ingredient_uid`, `Change_uid`, `Account`, `Name`, `Price`, `Tax_Type`, `Qty`, `Modifier`, `Modified`, `Deleted`) VALUES (6, 6, 1098, 0, 2, 'y', '1.0300', 31, 3, 0, '2019-09-27 15:54:23', 0);
INSERT INTO `orders_ingredient` (`ID`, `Item_ID`, `Ingredient_uid`, `Change_uid`, `Account`, `Name`, `Price`, `Tax_Type`, `Qty`, `Modifier`, `Modified`, `Deleted`) VALUES (7, 7, 1102, 0, 7, 'c', '2.8000', 31, 21, 0, '2020-06-04 13:15:17', 0);


#
# TABLE STRUCTURE FOR: orders_item
#

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `orders_item`;

CREATE TABLE `orders_item` (
  `ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Order_ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `Item_uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Account` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Qty` smallint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `Unit_Qty` decimal(13,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1.0000,
  `Unit_Type` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `Price` decimal(13,4) NOT NULL,
  `Tax_Type` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 31,
  `SplitID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `SplitBy` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `Category` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Combo` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `Service` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `Type` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `Printed` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `PrintDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Bill` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `Note` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Reason` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Void_By` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `Deleted` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `Combo` (`Combo`) USING BTREE COMMENT 'IMPORTANT GetComboItems',
  KEY `Order_ID` (`Order_ID`,`Type`,`Deleted`,`Price`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `Account` (`Account`,`Deleted`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC COMMENT='individual item per order'
 PARTITION BY RANGE (`ID`)
(PARTITION `pYear` VALUES LESS THAN (23) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `pCurrent` VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB);

INSERT INTO `orders_item` (`ID`, `Order_ID`, `Item_uid`, `Account`, `Name`, `Qty`, `Unit_Qty`, `Unit_Type`, `Price`, `Tax_Type`, `SplitID`, `SplitBy`, `Category`, `Combo`, `Service`, `Type`, `Printed`, `PrintDate`, `Bill`, `Note`, `Reason`, `Void_By`, `Modified`, `Deleted`) VALUES (1, 1, 3621, 90, '#009933', 20, '1.0000', 0, '2450.1800', 31, 0, 1, '9', 0, 0, 0, 0, '2019-07-23 05:35:33', 0, 'dicta', '', 0, '2020-03-16 23:05:47', 0);
INSERT INTO `orders_item` (`ID`, `Order_ID`, `Item_uid`, `Account`, `Name`, `Qty`, `Unit_Qty`, `Unit_Type`, `Price`, `Tax_Type`, `SplitID`, `SplitBy`, `Category`, `Combo`, `Service`, `Type`, `Printed`, `PrintDate`, `Bill`, `Note`, `Reason`, `Void_By`, `Modified`, `Deleted`) VALUES (2, 2, 1568, 0, '#00bb77', 3, '4.0000', 0, '936.3600', 31, 0, 1, '1', 0, 0, 0, 0, '2019-07-07 18:35:31', 0, 'consectetur', '', 0, '2019-08-14 15:27:05', 0);
INSERT INTO `orders_item` (`ID`, `Order_ID`, `Item_uid`, `Account`, `Name`, `Qty`, `Unit_Qty`, `Unit_Type`, `Price`, `Tax_Type`, `SplitID`, `SplitBy`, `Category`, `Combo`, `Service`, `Type`, `Printed`, `PrintDate`, `Bill`, `Note`, `Reason`, `Void_By`, `Modified`, `Deleted`) VALUES (3, 3, 9859, 2995758, '#00ff33', 7, '0.0000', 0, '1549.5800', 31, 0, 1, '4', 0, 0, 0, 0, '2020-06-17 04:05:57', 0, 'dolores', '', 0, '2019-12-23 09:07:34', 0);
INSERT INTO `orders_item` (`ID`, `Order_ID`, `Item_uid`, `Account`, `Name`, `Qty`, `Unit_Qty`, `Unit_Type`, `Price`, `Tax_Type`, `SplitID`, `SplitBy`, `Category`, `Combo`, `Service`, `Type`, `Printed`, `PrintDate`, `Bill`, `Note`, `Reason`, `Void_By`, `Modified`, `Deleted`) VALUES (4, 4, 5846, 8, '#00eeff', 14, '0.0000', 0, '1893.3800', 31, 0, 1, '7', 0, 0, 0, 0, '2020-05-03 07:36:27', 0, 'aut', '', 0, '2019-11-11 11:30:45', 0);
INSERT INTO `orders_item` (`ID`, `Order_ID`, `Item_uid`, `Account`, `Name`, `Qty`, `Unit_Qty`, `Unit_Type`, `Price`, `Tax_Type`, `SplitID`, `SplitBy`, `Category`, `Combo`, `Service`, `Type`, `Printed`, `PrintDate`, `Bill`, `Note`, `Reason`, `Void_By`, `Modified`, `Deleted`) VALUES (5, 5, 510, 55, '#0099bb', 1, '4.0000', 0, '1108.7100', 31, 0, 1, '1', 0, 0, 0, 0, '2019-11-10 03:00:26', 0, 'eligendi', '', 0, '2019-11-27 00:08:59', 0);
INSERT INTO `orders_item` (`ID`, `Order_ID`, `Item_uid`, `Account`, `Name`, `Qty`, `Unit_Qty`, `Unit_Type`, `Price`, `Tax_Type`, `SplitID`, `SplitBy`, `Category`, `Combo`, `Service`, `Type`, `Printed`, `PrintDate`, `Bill`, `Note`, `Reason`, `Void_By`, `Modified`, `Deleted`) VALUES (6, 6, 2351, 9420, '#007799', 14, '2.0000', 0, '1556.5000', 31, 0, 1, '9', 0, 0, 0, 0, '2020-04-07 16:30:04', 0, 'nam', '', 0, '2020-02-08 08:42:30', 0);
INSERT INTO `orders_item` (`ID`, `Order_ID`, `Item_uid`, `Account`, `Name`, `Qty`, `Unit_Qty`, `Unit_Type`, `Price`, `Tax_Type`, `SplitID`, `SplitBy`, `Category`, `Combo`, `Service`, `Type`, `Printed`, `PrintDate`, `Bill`, `Note`, `Reason`, `Void_By`, `Modified`, `Deleted`) VALUES (7, 7, 1466, 820, '#00cc77', 2, '5.0000', 0, '847.8000', 31, 0, 1, '9', 0, 0, 0, 0, '2019-10-30 16:22:48', 0, 'dolores', '', 0, '2019-08-08 08:03:33', 0);
INSERT INTO `orders_item` (`ID`, `Order_ID`, `Item_uid`, `Account`, `Name`, `Qty`, `Unit_Qty`, `Unit_Type`, `Price`, `Tax_Type`, `SplitID`, `SplitBy`, `Category`, `Combo`, `Service`, `Type`, `Printed`, `PrintDate`, `Bill`, `Note`, `Reason`, `Void_By`, `Modified`, `Deleted`) VALUES (8, 8, 8385, 807043258, '#0000ff', 7, '3.0000', 0, '291.0200', 31, 0, 1, '1', 0, 0, 0, 0, '2019-10-04 22:45:04', 0, 'aut', '', 0, '2019-10-29 01:09:58', 0);
INSERT INTO `orders_item` (`ID`, `Order_ID`, `Item_uid`, `Account`, `Name`, `Qty`, `Unit_Qty`, `Unit_Type`, `Price`, `Tax_Type`, `SplitID`, `SplitBy`, `Category`, `Combo`, `Service`, `Type`, `Printed`, `PrintDate`, `Bill`, `Note`, `Reason`, `Void_By`, `Modified`, `Deleted`) VALUES (9, 9, 2881, 21212542, '#009900', 17, '2.0000', 0, '1534.5200', 31, 0, 1, '6', 0, 0, 0, 0, '2019-10-27 03:26:07', 0, 'omnis', '', 0, '2020-03-05 01:17:56', 0);
INSERT INTO `orders_item` (`ID`, `Order_ID`, `Item_uid`, `Account`, `Name`, `Qty`, `Unit_Qty`, `Unit_Type`, `Price`, `Tax_Type`, `SplitID`, `SplitBy`, `Category`, `Combo`, `Service`, `Type`, `Printed`, `PrintDate`, `Bill`, `Note`, `Reason`, `Void_By`, `Modified`, `Deleted`) VALUES (10, 10, 3370, 648377, '#00ffcc', 14, '3.0000', 0, '2194.2900', 31, 0, 1, '4', 0, 0, 0, 0, '2020-02-09 13:08:07', 0, 'praesentium', '', 0, '2019-08-03 01:21:33', 0);
INSERT INTO `orders_item` (`ID`, `Order_ID`, `Item_uid`, `Account`, `Name`, `Qty`, `Unit_Qty`, `Unit_Type`, `Price`, `Tax_Type`, `SplitID`, `SplitBy`, `Category`, `Combo`, `Service`, `Type`, `Printed`, `PrintDate`, `Bill`, `Note`, `Reason`, `Void_By`, `Modified`, `Deleted`) VALUES (11, 1, 9632, 13229430, '#0022aa', 3, '4.0000', 0, '1481.0600', 31, 0, 1, '3', 0, 0, 0, 0, '2020-05-11 11:25:09', 0, 'magnam', '', 0, '2019-10-23 06:04:10', 0);
INSERT INTO `orders_item` (`ID`, `Order_ID`, `Item_uid`, `Account`, `Name`, `Qty`, `Unit_Qty`, `Unit_Type`, `Price`, `Tax_Type`, `SplitID`, `SplitBy`, `Category`, `Combo`, `Service`, `Type`, `Printed`, `PrintDate`, `Bill`, `Note`, `Reason`, `Void_By`, `Modified`, `Deleted`) VALUES (12, 2, 3025, 4796898, '#001122', 23, '0.0000', 0, '245.7700', 31, 0, 1, '2', 0, 0, 0, 0, '2019-06-27 13:08:55', 0, 'quod', '', 0, '2019-11-06 09:02:43', 0);
INSERT INTO `orders_item` (`ID`, `Order_ID`, `Item_uid`, `Account`, `Name`, `Qty`, `Unit_Qty`, `Unit_Type`, `Price`, `Tax_Type`, `SplitID`, `SplitBy`, `Category`, `Combo`, `Service`, `Type`, `Printed`, `PrintDate`, `Bill`, `Note`, `Reason`, `Void_By`, `Modified`, `Deleted`) VALUES (13, 3, 3658, 792, '#006677', 21, '0.0000', 0, '2151.8600', 31, 0, 1, '8', 0, 0, 0, 0, '2020-04-28 18:58:46', 0, 'ut', '', 0, '2019-10-05 02:12:20', 0);
INSERT INTO `orders_item` (`ID`, `Order_ID`, `Item_uid`, `Account`, `Name`, `Qty`, `Unit_Qty`, `Unit_Type`, `Price`, `Tax_Type`, `SplitID`, `SplitBy`, `Category`, `Combo`, `Service`, `Type`, `Printed`, `PrintDate`, `Bill`, `Note`, `Reason`, `Void_By`, `Modified`, `Deleted`) VALUES (14, 4, 590, 139, '#0077cc', 24, '0.0000', 0, '2328.8900', 31, 0, 1, '7', 0, 0, 0, 0, '2020-06-04 14:00:04', 0, 'et', '', 0, '2020-06-11 07:34:12', 0);
INSERT INTO `orders_item` (`ID`, `Order_ID`, `Item_uid`, `Account`, `Name`, `Qty`, `Unit_Qty`, `Unit_Type`, `Price`, `Tax_Type`, `SplitID`, `SplitBy`, `Category`, `Combo`, `Service`, `Type`, `Printed`, `PrintDate`, `Bill`, `Note`, `Reason`, `Void_By`, `Modified`, `Deleted`) VALUES (15, 5, 2551, 0, '#005599', 24, '4.0000', 0, '1370.6000', 31, 0, 1, '6', 0, 0, 0, 0, '2020-06-03 04:39:05', 0, 'quo', '', 0, '2019-12-29 07:27:46', 0);
INSERT INTO `orders_item` (`ID`, `Order_ID`, `Item_uid`, `Account`, `Name`, `Qty`, `Unit_Qty`, `Unit_Type`, `Price`, `Tax_Type`, `SplitID`, `SplitBy`, `Category`, `Combo`, `Service`, `Type`, `Printed`, `PrintDate`, `Bill`, `Note`, `Reason`, `Void_By`, `Modified`, `Deleted`) VALUES (16, 6, 447, 4573, '#008811', 14, '5.0000', 0, '161.5300', 31, 0, 1, '9', 0, 0, 0, 0, '2020-02-02 03:33:55', 0, 'facilis', '', 0, '2019-11-08 01:46:56', 0);
INSERT INTO `orders_item` (`ID`, `Order_ID`, `Item_uid`, `Account`, `Name`, `Qty`, `Unit_Qty`, `Unit_Type`, `Price`, `Tax_Type`, `SplitID`, `SplitBy`, `Category`, `Combo`, `Service`, `Type`, `Printed`, `PrintDate`, `Bill`, `Note`, `Reason`, `Void_By`, `Modified`, `Deleted`) VALUES (17, 7, 3342, 9994, '#00aabb', 5, '2.0000', 0, '839.2600', 31, 0, 1, '6', 0, 0, 0, 0, '2019-10-12 21:05:22', 0, 'non', '', 0, '2020-04-08 17:05:52', 0);
INSERT INTO `orders_item` (`ID`, `Order_ID`, `Item_uid`, `Account`, `Name`, `Qty`, `Unit_Qty`, `Unit_Type`, `Price`, `Tax_Type`, `SplitID`, `SplitBy`, `Category`, `Combo`, `Service`, `Type`, `Printed`, `PrintDate`, `Bill`, `Note`, `Reason`, `Void_By`, `Modified`, `Deleted`) VALUES (18, 8, 189, 0, '#003311', 6, '3.0000', 0, '1895.1300', 31, 0, 1, '7', 0, 0, 0, 0, '2019-08-14 03:41:34', 0, 'quaerat', '', 0, '2020-05-16 10:10:44', 0);


#
# TABLE STRUCTURE FOR: orders_option
#

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `orders_option`;

CREATE TABLE `orders_option` (
  `ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Item_ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `Option_uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Account` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Index_ID` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Value` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Price` decimal(13,4) NOT NULL,
  `Tax_Type` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 31,
  `Qty` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
  `Type` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `Item_ID` (`Item_ID`,`Price`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `Account` (`Account`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC COMMENT='individual item per order'
 PARTITION BY RANGE (`ID`)
(PARTITION `pYear` VALUES LESS THAN (2) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `pCurrent` VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB);

INSERT INTO `orders_option` (`ID`, `Item_ID`, `Option_uid`, `Account`, `Index_ID`, `Value`, `Price`, `Tax_Type`, `Qty`, `Type`, `Modified`) VALUES (1, 1, 352, 4, 0, 'r', '9.8400', 31, 16, 0, '2019-10-23 18:07:03');
INSERT INTO `orders_option` (`ID`, `Item_ID`, `Option_uid`, `Account`, `Index_ID`, `Value`, `Price`, `Tax_Type`, `Qty`, `Type`, `Modified`) VALUES (2, 2, 238, 9, 0, 'c', '4.8900', 31, 2, 0, '2020-06-18 07:08:15');
INSERT INTO `orders_option` (`ID`, `Item_ID`, `Option_uid`, `Account`, `Index_ID`, `Value`, `Price`, `Tax_Type`, `Qty`, `Type`, `Modified`) VALUES (3, 3, 189, 8, 0, 'y', '10.7900', 31, 2, 0, '2019-08-18 06:51:29');
INSERT INTO `orders_option` (`ID`, `Item_ID`, `Option_uid`, `Account`, `Index_ID`, `Value`, `Price`, `Tax_Type`, `Qty`, `Type`, `Modified`) VALUES (4, 4, 425, 6, 0, 's', '14.5500', 31, 4, 0, '2020-03-26 08:59:29');
INSERT INTO `orders_option` (`ID`, `Item_ID`, `Option_uid`, `Account`, `Index_ID`, `Value`, `Price`, `Tax_Type`, `Qty`, `Type`, `Modified`) VALUES (5, 5, 200, 3, 0, 'n', '13.9000', 31, 17, 0, '2020-01-29 11:05:18');

# Close_Date sorted Descending

SELECT Close_Date, 
       Count(*) 
FROM   orders 
GROUP  BY close_date 
ORDER  BY close_date DESC; 

# Closed Orders
SELECT ID, 
       Closed, 
       Deleted, 
       Close_Date 
FROM   orders 
WHERE  Closed = 1 
       AND DELETED = 0 
GROUP  BY id; 

# Closed Orders on Most Recent Close_Date
SELECT ID, 
       Closed, 
       Deleted,
       Close_Date 
FROM   orders 
WHERE  Closed=1
       AND Deleted=0
       AND Close_Date = (SELECT MAX(Close_Date)
                         FROM orders)
ORDER BY Close_Date DESC;

SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   (SELECT items.ID                   AS itemID, 
                       items.Order_ID             AS itemOrderID, 
                       items.Item_uid             AS itemPLU, 
                       items.Name                 AS itemName, 
                       items.Price                AS itemPrice, 
                       items.Qty                  AS itemQty, 
                       items.Category, 
                       ingredients.Item_ID        AS ingredientItemID, 
                       ingredients.Ingredient_uid AS ingredientPLU, 
                       ingredients.Name           AS ingredientName, 
                       ingredients.Qty            AS ingredientQty, 
                       ingredients.Price          AS ingredientPrice 
                FROM   orders_item AS items 
                       LEFT JOIN orders_ingredient AS ingredients 
                              ON items.ID = ingredients.Item_ID) AS 
               itemsIngredients 
               LEFT JOIN (SELECT Item_ID    AS optionItemID, 
                                 Option_uid AS optionPLU, 
                                 Price      AS optionPrice, 
                                 Value      AS optionName, 
                                 Qty        AS optionQty 
                          FROM   orders_option) AS options 
                      ON itemsIngredients.itemID = options.optionItemID) AS 
       itemsIngredientsOptions 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID         AS orderID, 
                         Table_ID   AS tableID, 
                         Closed     AS isClosed, 
                         Deleted    AS isDeleted, 
                         Close_Date as closeDate 
                  FROM   orders 
                  WHERE  Closed = 1 
                         AND Deleted = 1 
                         AND Close_Date = (SELECT Max(Close_Date) 
                                           FROM   orders)) AS closedOrders 
              ON orderID = closedOrders.orderID;
```

Extraneous tables and columns in the DB are left out.

In the end, the result I get is full of holes where I need data. The aliasing gets a little confusing and I'm having trouble keeping track of where I'm selecting from.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If it was me, I'd provide a minimal, complete, reproducible example. To that end, see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I can see the value there now that I read it. I'll work on this and edit ASAP.

Comment: This is way too much. PS Put what is needed for your question in your post, not just at a link. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. PS When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: Way too much. Noted. But why the mention of images? There are no images in my post. There’s also a MRE with the two queries. And I do believe I made mention of why I can’t post errors. I don’t get them. The code is there, inline.

Comment: The ERD is an image. (The content of an ERD is almost entirely expressed by DDL. Then typically the ERD is redundant. But--DDL is part of a MRE anyway.) There is not a MRE, eg there is not code that can be cut & pasted & run from the post, eg it is unclear what is given & what is wrong & what the 1 question is, eg the code in the post & links have way too many columns. Also there are about 4 (unclear) questions. PS Find out how to access error messages before you post or post a question re how, although it's probably a faq so not needing a post.

Comment: (I just saw your final comment to me below on an answer. See [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) to learn to use @x to notify one non-sole non-poster commenter x re a comment.) My comments & attitude are not negative, you are jumping to (wrong) conclusions. I agree I commented a lot, I commented more than usual here, a reflection of the question, I do try to not overwhelm. Thank you for your civility.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, I guess this turned into a classic X/Y scenario. @Strawberry's kind suggestion lead me to [filldb.info](http://filldb.info/) where I engineered a dummy local test scenario.

What bothered me was that I couldn't get any syntax errors to understand what was going wrong. With some help from commenters above, I was able to make a sample dummy of the db.

I know. Above is (was) a mess. And derived from a complete lack of bearings.

This gives me the result I need. By not understanding aliasing, and conditioning on a LEFT JOIN

```sql
SELECT orders.id                           AS orderID, 
       orders.closed                       AS closed, 
       orders.deleted                      AS deleted, 
       orders.close_date                   AS closeDate, 
       items.id                            AS itemID, 
       items.item_uid                      AS itemPLU, 
       items.NAME                          AS itemName, 
       items.category                      AS Category, 
       items.price                         AS itemPrice, 
       items.qty                           AS itemQty, 
       items.qty * items.price             AS itemRevenue, 
       options.option_uid                  AS optionPLU, 
       options.price                       AS optionPrice, 
       options.value                       AS optionName, 
       options.qty                         AS optionQty, 
       options.qty * options.price         AS optionRevenue, 
       ingredients.ingredient_uid          AS ingredientPLU, 
       ingredients.NAME                    AS ingredientName, 
       ingredients.qty                     AS ingredientQty, 
       ingredients.price                   AS ingredientPrice, 
       ingredients.qty * ingredients.price AS ingredientsRevenue 
FROM   orders_item AS items 
       LEFT JOIN orders_ingredient AS ingredients 
              ON ingredients.item_id = items.id 
       LEFT JOIN orders_option AS options 
              ON options.item_id = items.id 
       LEFT JOIN orders 
              ON items.order_id = orders.id 
WHERE  orders.closed = 1 
       AND orders.deleted = 0 
       AND orders.close_date = (SELECT Max(close_date) 
                                FROM   orders);
```

I get a row that is a record of each item sold for the day requested, including the options and ingredients a customer has added to the item, along with all the required data.

Thank you to all who gave me pointers, brutal or otherwise.

Comment: Just to observe, orders is an INNER JOIN

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? @strawberry

Comment: If you execute EXPLAIN EXTENDED [your query], followed by SHOW WARNINGS, you'll hopefullly see what I mean, but, in essence, MySQL silently converts `LEFT JOIN x... WHERE x = ...` to `INNER JOIN x...`

Comment: Okay. I see it. the `SHOW  WARNINGS` query shows the silent change and from `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Comment: Please put what is needed for a post in the post. Links die. And just what is needed. Less is more. PS This is not minimal. All those selected columns are just noise. PS Please do not use strikeouts or insert/append EDITs/UPDATEs. Edit your post to be the best self-contained presentation as of time of writing. PS Please avoid greetings, thanks, feelings, narratives etc. Just present what is directly relevant to the Q&A. [help]

Comment: LEFT JOIN ON returns INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN ON you want as part of an OUTER JOIN ON. After a LEFT JOIN ON, a WHERE, INNER JOIN or HAVING that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL removes any rows with introduced NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN ON rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Comment: @philipxy thanks for your brutally honest feedback.

Comment: I don't mean to be brutal, just straightforward.

Answer (score -1):

For starters,

```
 (SELECT MAX(orders.Close_Date))
```

needs to be

```
 (SELECT MAX(Close_Date) FROM orders)
```

To optimize

```
WHERE
    orders.Closed = 1
    AND orders.Deleted=0
    AND orders.Close_Date =
```

`orders` needs

```
INDEX(Closed, Deleted, Close_Date)   -- in any order
```

This pattern is usually inefficient; try to flatten the query.

```
FROM ( SELECT ... ) JOIN ( SELECT ... ) ON ...
```

`,SODA ,` -- consider removing trailing blanks on the way in.  Else you may stumble over `'SODA' != 'SODA '`.

"objective is to get a nice bit of data in tidy form" -- But is CSV a tidy form?  What will be done with it?

Comment: Yeah, I see it. Thanks. I had added that quickly at the end. Fixed in edit. Re. CSV was just the only format at the time I knew how to make quickly available for someone grab. I'm pretty much a noob lol. Mathematician-as-jack-of-all-trades.

Comment: Oh! and...

The tidy form I mean is one-obeservation-one-line; columns are variables. Then the data parsed on our end, and passed to our platform where we put it to various uses in monitoring prime costs for food-and-beverage operations: cafes, restos, institutional, you name it. We're building integrations with POS systems.

Comment: I was going to do any text pre-processing on our end since the API returns a proper JSON formatted string (escaped double quotes and all), we'd have to process all the numerical data back to numerical anyway. And, I'll be doing that work on the cloud, with more available compute power. I want to do as little work on their servers as possible.

Comment: @TheMathochist - Don't let him ruffle you.  I guess he downvoted me, too.  I tend to focus on optimization; I gave you some tips in that direction.  Looks like you figured out your question -- good.  I suggest you take the "tutorial"; it's an easy +100 reputation.

Comment: I haven't downvoted answers here. My comment to you (like others on this page) was neutral & clearly trying to help @TheMathochist & help you help people. Disagreement isn't attack. Moreover on their posts other than signal-to-noise I only initially addressed format & *missing* content, even though I agree with them that "Above is a mess".

Comment: This is the last I'll say, as I think it should be said. I'm referring to your method of criticizing. Not the criticism. There is a difference between straight forward and being unnecessarily heavy handed. 6 comments? quoting the Help Guide? Chiding a user for giving an answer instead of downvoting/voting to close? Just say it to me. once. "This post is too long. Have a look here. I'm voting to close. If you can fix it up great, if not, oh well." Not hard. At least @strawberry was helpful. With that, be well and ease up on the noobs. And I'll deal with this mess. Thanks for the advice.